# Stop counting to a specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have to count the number of sheets but not until the end of worksheets. The counting should stop when a sheet named `"final"` is reached without being counted. 
This sheet somewhere in between the sheets. So `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` doesn't work.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.Index` of the worksheet `final` returns its position. So subtract `1` and you have the amount of worksheets before `final`:

```
Dim SheetCountUntilFinal As Long
SheetCountUntilFinal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("final").Index - 1
```

Comment: That is what i was missing: the .index! attribute. Thank You!